# Wrong Page.GetRouteUrl() in asp.net 4.0 application. Any help for URL routing

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, routes

I am creating asp.net web application with web forms, I am using register routes to product friendly URL's.

Following is the code in Global.asax.cs;

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

```
    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // Register a route for Categories/All
        routes.MapPageRoute(
           "All Categories",      // Route name
           "Categories/All",      // Route URL
           "~/AllCategories.aspx" // Web page to handle route
        );

        // Route to handle Categories/{CategoryName}. 
        // The {*CategoryName} instructs the route to match all content after the first slash, which is needed b/c some category names contain a slash, as in the category "Meat/Produce"
        // See http://forums.asp.net/p/1417546/3131024.aspx for more information
        routes.MapPageRoute(
           "View Category",               // Route name
           "Categories/{*CategoryName}",  // Route URL
           "~/CategoryProducts.aspx"      // Web page to handle route
        );
        // Register a route for Products/{ProductName}
        routes.MapPageRoute(
           "View All Product",           // Route name
           "Products", // Route URL
           "~/ViewProducts.aspx"      // Web page to handle route
        );


        // Register a route for Products/{ProductName}
        routes.MapPageRoute(
           "View Product",           // Route name
           "Product/{ProductName}", // Route URL
           "~/ViewProduct.aspx"      // Web page to handle route
        );


        // Register a route for Products/{ProductName}
        routes.MapPageRoute(
           "Add Product",           // Route name
           "NewProduct", // Route URL
           "~/AddProduct.aspx"      // Web page to handle route
        );


    }
```

Now in one page when I put

```
        lnkNewProduct.NavigateUrl = Page.GetRouteUrl("Add Product");
```

It produce wrong href url when I run the project.

Can anyone please tell why this happen? At moment it is showing URL like http:\localhost:5770\Categories\All?Length=11... this is hard to understand.

Any hint or help???

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the correct overload:

```
Page.GetRouteUrl("Add Products", null);
```

This `GetRouteUrl` overload uses the *RouteName*.

You can use Route Url expressions also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.routeurlexpressionbuilder.aspx